# How to add duplicate key elements in JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript

I want to make the following newArray using by following `testArray`.

**newArray↓**

```
    let newArray = [
        {section:"business",name:["Bob","John"]},
        {section:"H&R",name:["Jen","Bobby"]},
    ]
```

**testArray↓**

```
let test = [
    {section:"business",name:"Bob"},
    {section:"business",name:"John"},
    {section:"H&R",name:"Jen"},
    {section:"H&R",name:"Bobby"},
]
```

First of all, I tried to find some key elements using by filter method like below.

```
let newArray = test.filter((x:any,i,self)=>
                  self.indexOf(x.section)===i
             )
```

but this code output is [].
So, how do I make code to get my expected output?
Does anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.reduce()`:

```js
let test=[{section:"business",name:"Bob"},{section:"business",name:"John"},{section:"H&R",name:"Jen"},{section:"H&R",name:"Bobby"}];

let newArray = test.reduce((acc,cur) => {
  if(acc.some(el => el.section === cur.section)){
    acc.forEach((el,idx) => {
      if(el.section === cur.section){
        acc[idx].name.push(cur.name)
      }
    })
  }else{
    cur.name = [cur.name]
    acc.push(cur)
  }
  return acc
},[])

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```js
const test = [{
    section: "business",
    name: "Bob"
  },
  {
    section: "business",
    name: "John"
  },
  {
    section: "H&R",
    name: "Jen"
  },
  {
    section: "H&R",
    name: "Bobby"
  },
];

// gather sections
const sections = {};
test.forEach(t => {
  sections[t.section] = sections[t.section] || [];
  sections[t.section].push(t.name);
});

// convert sessions to array
const newArray = Object.keys(sections).map(k => {
  return {
    section: k,
    name: sections[k]
  };
});

console.log(newArray);
```